# Brunch, RequireJS, and ReactJS is giving me "Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module"

Tags: javascript, requirejs, reactjs, brunch

**The problem:**
I cant get React.js to function at all in a requirejs and brunch situation.

I get a mismatched definition error with the react.js library, and react does not show up in the windows object.I am unsure as to what to do, and was hoping some one here had guidance in how resolve this issue. Perhaps I am using this combination of technology incorrectly, maybe it is not possible? Any insight into what I may be doing wrong or suggestions to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Btw, If I remove the bower reference to react.js, and remove all react.js information from the application, it all works correctly.

See my below edit for some additional comments and findings!

**Actual error:**

> Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){var
>   define,module,exports;return (function e(t,n,r){function
>   s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof
>   require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return
>   i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw
>   f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var
>   l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var
>   n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return
>   n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var
>   o=0;odereq,module,exports){*

**The Project file structure is as follows:**

```
Projectname
 |-app
   |-assets
     |-index.html
   |-components
     |-appinit.js
   |-styles
 |-bower_components
   |-react
   |-requirejs
 |-node_modules
 |-public
 |-bower.json
 |-brunch.config
```

**The brunch.config file**, I believe is pretty standard, here are the contents:

```
exports.config = {
    "modules": {
        "definition" : "amd",
        "wrapper" : "amd"
    },
    "files": {
        "stylesheets": {
            "defaultExtension": "css",
            "joinTo": {
                "css/app.css": /^app\/styles/,
                "css/vendor.css": /^(bower_components|vendor)/
            }
        },
        "javascripts": {
            "joinTo": {
                "js/app.js": /^app/,
                "js/vendor.js": /^(bower_components|vendor)[\\/]/,
                "test/js/test.js": /^test(\/|\\)(?!vendor)/,
                "test/js/test-vendor.js": /^test(\/|\\)(?=vendor)/
            },
            "order": {
                "before": [
                    'bower_components/requirejs/require.js'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Here are the contents for the **index.html file**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>My Application Test</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
        <script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
        <script>
            require.config({
                "paths": {
                    "react": "bower_components/react/react-with-addons"
                },
                "shim": {
                    "react": {
                        exports: "React"
                    }
                },
                waitSeconds: 10
            });

            require(["components/appinit"], function (appInit) {
                appInit.init();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="height:100%; width:100%;">
        <div id="main-content" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 22px;">
            My Main Content Goes Here.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the contents of **the appinit.js file**:

```
define(function() {
    var mainModule;

    return mainModule = {
        init: function () {
            console.log("This is a test.");
            return mainModule;
        }
    };
});
```

**The bower.json file** contains the following:

```
{
  "name": “brunchreactrequirejstest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": "",
  "authors": [
    “person x"
  ],
  "description": “description",
  "main": "public/js/app.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "requirejs": "~2.1.15",
    "react": "~0.12.2"
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

So I believe I am getting closer to getting this resolved. I just found out that brunch only adds the definition wrappers around non-vendor javascript. So, react.js is being compiled to the vendor.js file without any definition name, so require.js throws the exception of react.js being anonymous. So, perhaps I need to have brunch run r.js on the vendor file during the compilation process? Does this sound correct? How do I go about doing that in brunch?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/28

Comment: Hi es128, ill take a look at this thread and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible Solution:**

So I have react now functioning in a requirejs(AMD) environment. There is one problem that I see with my approach, and that is that I believe some libraries that work with react expect react to be exposed as a global object.I believe I can probably shim this into the requirejs export.config() by creating a requirejs definition that manually places react into the browser window scope(more on this later.)

Following are the changes I have made that have allowed react to work in an AMD/RequireJS environment:

**The (new) brunch.config file:**

```
exports.config = {
    "modules": {
        "definition" : "amd",
        "wrapper" : "amd"
    },
    "files": {
        "stylesheets": {
            "defaultExtension": "css",
            "joinTo": {
                "css/app.css": /^app\/styles/,
                "css/vendor.css": /^(bower_components|vendor)/
            }
        },
        "javascripts": {
            "joinTo": {
                "js/app.js": /^app/,
                "js/vendor.js": /^(bower_components|vendor)[\\/](?!react\/)/,
                "test/js/test.js": /^test(\/|\\)(?!vendor)/,
                "test/js/test-vendor.js": /^test(\/|\\)(?=vendor)/
            },
            "order": {
                "before": [
                    'bower_components/requirejs/require.js'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "plugins":{
        "react": {
                "harmony": "yes"
            }
    }
};
```

**The (new) index.html 'head' now only consists of this:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
<script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script>
    require(["components/appinit"], function (appInit) {
        appInit.init();
    });
</script>
```

**The build.js file:** So this file i created is executed by node.js when I call 'npm start' on the project, which you will see in the package.json file further below:

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    optimize: "none",
    paths: {
        react: "bower_components/react/react-with-addons"
    },
    name: "react",
    out: "vendor/react-built.js"
})
```

basically, it assigns the bower path to the react path, and the name grabs the bower path so that it knows the location of the file that r.js will optimize. The require.js optimized file is then thrown into the vendor folder as react-built.js. If you recall from above, in my new brunch config file, I exclude the bower-react javascript library from being compiled into the final vendor.js file, because i will already be adding the requirejs optimized react library that is generated with this build.js file.

**So the scripts section of the NPM package.json file looks like this:**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js -o build.js && brunch watch --server"
  }
```

Essentially, when you call 'npm start', r.js is executed with the build.js file passed into it, afterwards brunch is called.

So the next part, as es128 has mentioned, is to get any JSX annotated files to get preprocessed into javascript before brunch wraps them for AMD inclusion.

**== Edit**
So installing the react-brunch plugin via npm works wonderfully. .jsx files get compiled to javascript upon saving the .jsx file. I updated the above brunch-config file with the plugin information. I have yet to shim and export React globally into the window scope, but I believe that may be a different StackOverflow topic since it does not relate to my original question.

Comment: Adding the react-brunch plugin ought to compile your jsx files to js within the brunch pipeline, after which brunch will wrap each one as an amd module.

Comment: @es128 You and I are thinking alike! I came across the same plugin and I will embed it into the application tonight. If all is good, I will give this answer the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

The React project does not provide an AMD interface out of the box, and as you noted in your edit this is not something Brunch will do for you on vendor files.

Your options appear to be either converting your project to use CommonJS module patterns or use an AMD adapter such as https://github.com/philix/jsx-requirejs-plugin.

Comment: Thanks es128 for your suggestions. I had taken a look at the jsx-requirejs-plugin, but it seemed to me that all it did was to preprocess your JSX written files into javascript and did nothing to resolve the AMD interface for the react.js library. Granted, I actually did not try to use this plugin, so my assumptions on it may be incorrect. It also seems like the preprocessing that this plugin performs would occur outside the brunch scope, so i would have to do an 'npm start' every time i changed one of the jsx files, instead of having brunch watch for changes and automatically transform them.

Comment: That said, I believe I have a solution for having react function in an AMD environment, so please take a look at the second set of edits I added and tell me what you think.